# Center-aligning a Facebook share button

Tags: html, css, styling

I have this page:

http://www.comehike.com/hiking.php

```
        <div style="align:center">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=217585988283772&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false" action="recommend" font=""></fb:like>
        </div>
```

And I am using this code to try to center-align the Facebook share button, but it isn't happening.

Any idea how I can center-align it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 390px;">
```

Comment: The way you center div is by setting the width equal to the contents of the div and then by adding the "margin: 0 auto;" property. I think with "align: center" you were actually meaning "text-align: center" which will only center the text within the confines of an element. I see you have modified your code a bit to show only the "Recommend" button, and thus the width of the div must change due to the content changing. Try 100px. If you use Firefox, a good tool for determining the width of your div's contents is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon./measureit/.

Comment: This also works with the Facebook Page Plugin.  Set the width to 500px and add `max-width: 100%` for a responsive embed.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but this worked for me:

```
<div style='text-align: center;' class="fb-like" 
         data-href="https://www.facebook.com/georgerrmartinofficial" 
         data-layout="standard" 
         data-action="like" 
         data-show-faces="true" 
         data-share="true"></div>
```